# CMake set project to C++ 20

Tags: c++, cmake, c++20

I am trying to change the C++ Standard from version 17 to 20 so I can use the jthread lib.

On my root CMakelists.txt of the project I added :

```
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 20)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED YES)
```

But when I build the project again and check which version the program is running, it is still the C++ 17 version and not C++ 20.

I check the version running the following lines :

```
if (__cplusplus == 201703L)
    std::cout << "C++17\n";
else if (__cplusplus == 201402L)
    std::cout << "C++14\n";
else if (__cplusplus == 201103L)
    std::cout << "C++11\n";
else if (__cplusplus == 199711L)
    std::cout << "C++98\n";
else if (__cplusplus == 202002L)
    std::cout << "C++20\n";

else
    std::cout << "pre-standard C++\n";
```

I am using the g++ (Ubuntu 9.4.0-1ubuntu1~20.04.1) 9.4.0, which from what I read it supports c++ 20,[g++_C++20](https://www.google.com/search?q=c%2B%2B%20version%2020%20g%2B%2B&rlz=1C1GCEA_enPT1025PT1025&oq=c%2B%2B%20version%2020%20g%2B%2B%20&aqs=chrome..69i57j0i22i30i625.5607j0j4&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8#:%7E:text=GCC%20has%20experimental%20support%20for%20the%20latest%20revision%20of%20the%20C%2B%2B%20standard%2C%20which%20was%20published%20in%202020.%20C%2B%2B20%20features%20are%20available%20since%20GCC%208.%20To%20enable%20C%2B%2B20%20support%2C%20add%20the%20command%2Dline%20parameter%20%2Dstd%3Dc%2B%2B20%20(use%20%2Dstd%3Dc%2B%2B2a%20in%20GCC%209%20and%20earlier)%20to%20your%20g%2B%2B%20command%20line)

Does anyone has any idea of why this is happening ?

Comment: This is still under development. [Here you can check list of C++20 features](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/compiler_support/20) which has been implemented and since which version of compiler it is available.

Comment: gcc 9.4 do not support C++20, only some features are available, so flag `-std=c++2a` is used (`-std=c++20` will not work). That is why `__cplusplus` gives: `201709` https://godbolt.org/z/eTYnW17n6 Apparently `cmake` was to smart and used  `-std=c++2a`. Please check build logs more carefully (possibly use verbose mode).

Comment: did you clear your cmake cache after making this change?

Comment: looks like gcc 11 is the first version to report c++20 in `__cplusplus` https://godbolt.org/z/oKG6eG5xP

Comment: Note that checking the support of some version of the standard is a bit "fragile" in general. For instance, even Clang 15 with `-std=c++20` evaluates `__cplusplus` to `202002`, but it doesn't mean that it supports all the C++20 features (https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/compiler_support#cpp20).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`__cplusplus` reports the version of the standard but its definition isn't entirely clear. GCC seems to only define it to `202002` from GCC 11 when presumably the implementation reached some arbitrary level of completion.

It is instead better to test for the existence of the specific feature you want to use using the [feature test macros](https://en.cppreference.com/w/User:D41D8CD98F/feature_testing_macros) for example to check for `std::jthread` support:

```
#include <thread>

#ifndef __cpp_lib_jthread
#error this code requires std::jthread
#endif
```

Note that `std::jthread` is only available with libstdc++ 10: https://godbolt.org/z/eqP4j4eq1