How to import ThunderKittens in my C++ cmake project and make #include "kittens.cuh" work?
I want to use the ThunderKittens repository in my C++ project, specifically to include the kittens.cuh header file. I've cloned the repository, but I'm unsure how to configure my CMake project to integrate it properly. I want to make the following code work:
#include "kittens.cuh"

I added the following code in cmake:
include_directories(tensor  "D:\\Code\\Cpp\\tensor\\ThunderKittens\\include")

But the code doesn't run:
Error limit reached.
100 errors detected in the compilation of "D:/Code/Cpp/tensor/main.cu".
Compilation terminated.
main.cu
ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.

The following is a minimal reproducible example:
cmakelists.txt:
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.18 FATAL_ERROR)
project(tensor LANGUAGES CXX C CUDA)


set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} ${TORCH_CXX_FLAGS}")
set(DCMAKE_CUDA_COMPIRLER "C:\\Program Files\\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\\CUDA\\v12.1\\bin\nvcc.exe")

add_executable(tensor main.cu)
include_directories(tensor  "D:\\Code\\Cpp\\tensor\\ThunderKittens\\include")
set_property(TARGET tensor PROPERTY CXX_STANDARD 20)

cmake command:
"E:\IDE\CLion 2023.3.4\bin\cmake\win\x64\bin\cmake.exe" --debugger --debugger-pipe=\\.\pipe\cmake-debug-23700-1 -S D:\Code\Cpp\tensor -B D:\Code\Cpp\tensor\cmake-build-debug -G Ninja -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug "-DCMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM=E:/IDE/CLion 2023.3.4/bin/ninja/win/x64/ninja.exe" -DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=D:\CodeLauguage\Python\Lib\site-packages\torch\share\cmake "-DCMAKE_CUDA_COMPIRLER=C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v12.1\bin\nvcc.exe" 

main.cu

#include <kittens.cuh>

int main() {
    return 0;
}

run command:
"E:\IDE\CLion 2023.3.4\bin\cmake\win\x64\bin\cmake.exe" --build D:\Code\Cpp\tensor\cmake-build-debug --target tensor -j 22

The errors are very long, and the first five of them are shown here:
D:\Code\Cpp\tensor\ThunderKittens\include\common\base_types.cuh(47): error: identifier "concept" is undefined
  concept T2 = std::is_same_v<T, float2> || std::is_same_v<T, bf16_2> || std::is_same_v<T, half_2>; 
  ^

D:\Code\Cpp\tensor\ThunderKittens\include\common\base_types.cuh(49): error: identifier "concept" is undefined
  concept T1 = std::is_same_v<T, float>  || std::is_same_v<T, bf16  > || std::is_same_v<T, half>; 
  ^

D:\Code\Cpp\tensor\ThunderKittens\include\common\base_types.cuh(95): error: namespace "std" has no member "bit_cast"
      static __declspec(__device__) inline constexpr bf16 zero()      { return std::bit_cast<__nv_bfloat16>(uint16_t(0x0000)); } 
                                                                                    ^

D:\Code\Cpp\tensor\ThunderKittens\include\common\base_types.cuh(95): error: type name is not allowed
      static __declspec(__device__) inline constexpr bf16 zero()      { return std::bit_cast<__nv_bfloat16>(uint16_t(0x0000)); } 
                                                                                             ^

D:\Code\Cpp\tensor\ThunderKittens\include\common\base_types.cuh(96): error: namespace "std" has no member "bit_cast"
      static __declspec(__device__) inline constexpr bf16 one()       { return std::bit_cast<__nv_bfloat16>(uint16_t(0x3F80)); }


Does your compiler support c++20? Also set_property(TARGET tensor PROPERTY CXX_STANDARD 20) isn't really the correct CMake way to enable c++20 related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75010206/cuda-12-c20-support-with-cmake-not-working

I modify cmakelist.txt:cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.25.2 FATAL_ERROR) project(tensor LANGUAGES CXX C CUDA) set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 20) set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON) set(CMAKE_CUDA_STANDARD 20) set(CMAKE_CUDA_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON) but it still error

I see no evidence anywhere in that project that it has even been tested with the Microsoft toolchain on windows.

cmake build "E:\IDE\CLion 2023.3.4\bin\cmake\win\x64\bin\cmake.exe" --debugger --debugger-pipe=\\.\pipe\cmake-debug-23700-1 -S D:\Code\Cpp\tensor -B D:\Code\Cpp\tensor\cmake-build-debug -G Ninja -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug "-DCMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM=E:/IDE/CLion 2023.3.4/bin/ninja/win/x64/ninja.exe" -DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=D:\CodeLauguage\Python\Lib\site-packages\torch\share\cmake "-DCMAKE_CUDA_COMPIRLER=C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v12.1\bin\nvcc.exe" Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v12.1\bin\nvcc.exe

run main:````"E:\IDE\CLion 2023.3.4\bin\cmake\win\x64\bin\cmake.exe" --build D:\Code\Cpp\tensor\cmake-build-debug --target tensor -j 22


simple case: c++20 is not enabled. Enable it. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75296149/cmake-set-project-to-c-20
